# If only one element in a hashset, how can I get it out?

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have a `set` like below:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
```

How can I get the `1` out? I can do it by `for(integer i : set)`. My specified problem is "Given an array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one."

I want to use add elements into the set if the set doesn't contain it and remove existing elements during the loop. And the last remaining element is the answer. I don't know how to return it.

```java
public static int singleNumber(int[] A) {
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int a : A) {
        if (!set.contains(a)) {
            set.add(a);
        } else {
            set.remove(a);
        }
    }
    /**
     * for(Integer i : set) { return i; }
     *return A[0]; //need one useless return
     /**
     * while(set.iterator().hasNext()) { return set.iterator().next(); }
     * return A[0]; //need one useless return
     */
    return set.toArray(new Integer[1])[0];
}
```

Comment: That's the only way. A `Set` doesn't provide any method for data retrieval.

Comment: It may be interesting to know what do you want this for. Your use case...

Comment: What do you mean by "get it out". Does it mean retrieve it, or does it mean remove it?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos OP can do it by `for(integer i : set)` it means OP is interested in data retrieval rather than data removal.

Comment: @Luiggi, Are you sure ? What about the `keySet` method.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan I don't know any `keySet` method in `Set` interface.

Comment: @Luiggi, my bad, apologizes.

Comment: I just tried to use `return set.iterator().next()`. However, it have to use like `while(set.iterator().hasNext()) {return set.iterator().next(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try using `HashSet#toArray()` method

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);

if (set.size() == 1) { // make sure that there is only one element in set
    Integer value = set.toArray(new Integer[1])[0];
    System.out.println(value);//output 1
}
```

Answer (score 13):

`set.iterator().next()`

Do so only if you are sure there is an element in the set. Otherwise `next()` will throw an exception.

Comment: I have tried this like return set.iterator().next(), it will return exception.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution includes a check if the current iterator position has any left element through `setIterator.hasNext()` which returns `true` only if there is an extra element unchecked. For example

```
HashSet set = new HashSet(); 
Iterator setIterator = set.iterator();
while(setIterator.hasNext()){
   String item = setIterator().next();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the element is and you just want to empty the set, you can use `remove(Object o)` (or `clear()` for that matter). If you don't know what it is and want to see it without removing it, use an iterator. If you don't know what it is and want to remove it, you should use an iterator using the iterator's `remove()` method. This is the safe (and recommended) way to remove elements from a collection. Since Set is unordered, it's difficult to specify what you want to remove. And for any collection, you would usually only know what you are removing if you iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution Using Java Stream

If you want to use [Java Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) any of the following options will give you the desired result:

### Option 1

Just return the only element from the stream:

`set.stream().findFirst().get()`

### Option 2

Or use `Stream.reduce`; since adding the only element to zero has no effect

(*a little too much IMHO :)*)

`set.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)`

You can test it [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/AxG).